# Azure diagnostics configuration after reimaging

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics

With Azure SDK 2.5 the configuration of diagnostics changed. 
I am now configuring diagnostics with powershell command Set-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension.

I am normally wary about changing thins in my azure deployment via powershell because I am always unsure where the things are persisted.

Here's my question: 
When I use Set-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension, will it survive:
* Reimaging of the webrole
* Refresh/upload of a new version
* Creation of a new instance?

Where is the diagnostics configuration saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the diagnostics configuration will survive all of those operations.  The diagnostics configuration is stored as an extension, which is part of the cloud service (the parent cloud service, not just one of the slots).  Any time something happens to your role (ie. a ReImage) the guest agent in the VM will install any extensions configured for that deployment and role.